# Is it good practice for a Clojure record to implement IFn?

Tags: function, clojure, functional-programming, record

Suppose I have a record that is "function-like", at least in the sense that it represents an operation that could be applied to some arguments.

I can make it work as a function by implementing `clojure.lang.IFn`, something like:

```
(defrecord Func [f x]
  clojure.lang.IFn
    (invoke [this arg]
      (f x arg))
    (applyTo [this args]
      (apply f x args)))

 ((->Func + 7) 1)
 => 8
```

(yes I know that I've just reimplemented an inferior version of `partial`.... it's just an example :-) )

Is making a record implement `clojure.lang.IFn` a good practice or not?

Any pitfalls to this approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm surprised it doesn't already. Records are supposed to be ["a complete implementation of a persistent map"](http://clojure.org/datatypes).  So to answer your question, I'd expect it to be a function of its keys, as a map is; anything else would be quite surprising.

Comment: A record seems to implement `clojure.lang.Associative` but not `clojure.lang.IFn`. So you can do `(:a some-record)` to look up the keyword but not `(some-record :x)`

Comment: Precisely.  I've checked but haven't seen anything explicit about this from Rich.  Perhaps it's just an oversight.

Comment: +1 given because @mikera's question asks about records not types. Because records have map-like semantics already it would be confusing, for types this problem isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I can not give a direct Yes/No answer, but I can share my experience.

I defined a record implemented `clojure.lang.IFn`. Implementing IFn was to let me test it through REPL environment easily.

That record was intended to be a Job class, which was going to be processed by a worker. Therefore, I also implemented another interface `java.lang.Runnable` and a `run` function.

When I really put the code into integration test, it threw exception. Why?

The worker logic was something like this:

1. It checked if the Job class is a `Callable` instance, if so, invoke the `call` function.
2. It checked if the Job class is a `Runnable` instance, if so, invoke the `run` function.

However, `clojure.lang.IFn` has already extended `Callable` and `Runnable`, so the exception raised because I forgot to implement the `call` function.